# php SQL query inserting records in wrong column

Tags: php, sql, ado

I have this code to select data from one table and move it to another one while in array.

```
<?php 
// CHANGE THE CONNECTION INFORMATION TO YOUR DETAILS (OFF YOU CARD)
//$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root");


$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn->Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; ..");

$conn2 = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn2->Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=...;
Initial Catalog=...; User ID=...; Password=...");


$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT ColourID, Width, Height, Price FROM VS_Matrix");    // Recordset

$num_rows = $rs->Fields->Count();

for ($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    $fld[$i] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $fld2[$i] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $fld3[$i] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $fld4[$i] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $x= 469;


}

$rowcount = 0;
while (!$rs->EOF) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
        echo $fld[$i]->value . "\t";

$rs2 = $conn2->Execute("INSERT INTO TST (ID, ColourID, Width, Height, Price) VALUES ('".$x."','".$fld[$i]."','".$fld2[$i]."','".$fld3[$i]."','".$fld4[$i]."')"); 

    }




    echo "\n";
    $rowcount++;   
        $x=$x+1;     // increments rowcount
    $rs->MoveNext();
}

$rs->Close();
$conn->Close();

$rs = null;
$conn = null;
```

For some reason its placing records seemingly at random probably cause I made a silly mistake. Anyone can spot it?

Comment: Is it an issue that you're only ever assigning `$x= 469;`, and using that as the ID in TST? Otherwise, you're going to have to explain slightly more in-depth as to what "placing records at random" means.

Comment: seems that you have the same value in all your $fld[$i] variables

Comment: the x is to avoid the id unique constraint

Comment: should i do a different select for every rs then?

Comment: @vast365 you can fetch field values from resource in while loop

Comment: I m sorry for asking that user15 but i m really stressed atm can you give me a short example that might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP manual user comments [PHP: COM - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php):

```
    $rows=0;
    while(!$rs->EOF) {
        for($i=0;$i<$rs->Fields->count;$i++) {
            $rsf = $rs->Fields($i);
            if($associative) $rtn[$rows][$rsf->Name] = $rsf->value;
            else $rtn[$rows][$i] = $rsf->value;
        }
        $rows++;
        $rs->MoveNext();
    }
```

After this you'll have `$rtn` where `$rtn[$row]` - is an array which consist of values of one row of database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm not sure why you're doing all this extra work. Assuming ID is an AUTO_INCREMENT you can just:

```
INSERT INTO TST (ColourID, Width, Height, Price) 
SELECT ColourID, Width, Height, Price FROM VS_Matrix
```